# Swap Elements of Array in Python in One Line [Failed Memory Reference]

Tags: python, reference, sharedpreferences, partitioning, swap

Given the following Array:

A = [11, 0, 9, 2, 7], I want to **swap** A[0] and A[3].

**Expected result**: A = [2, 0, 9, 11, 7].

Can someone explain why the first and the second method **failed**? I am suspecting this has to do with **memory reference.** Any thoughts?

### First Approach (FAILED)

```
A = [11, 0, 9, 2, 7]
print("Original:",A)    
temp = A[0]    
temp, A[3] = A[3], temp    
print("First:   ",A)
```

### Second Approach (FAILED)

```
A = [11, 0, 9, 2, 7]
temp = A[0]
A[3], temp = temp, A[3]
print("Second:  ",A)
```

### Third Approach (Worked)

```
A = [11, 0, 9, 2, 7]
A[0], A[3] = A[3], A[0]
print("Third:   ",A)
```

### Fourth Approach (Worked)

```
A = [11, 0, 9, 2, 7]
temp = A[0] # p = 11
A[0] = A[3]
A[3] = temp 
print("Fourth:  ",A)
```

## RESULTS

**Original**: [11, 0, 9, 2, 7]

**First (Failed):**     [11, 0, 9, 11, 7]

**Second (Failed):**    [11, 0, 9, 11, 7]

**Third (Success):**    [2, 0, 9, 11, 7]

**Fourth (Success):**   [2, 0, 9, 11, 7]

Answer (score 0):

Because in 1st and 2nd you are swapping values between temp and A[3]
But not doing it for A[0]
just do
**A[0] = temp**

As you have don in 3rd

**"temp" is a variable outside the list.**
be carefull